# Converting Lat/Lot from OSG36 to Lat/Lot in WG84?

Tags: fme-form, fmeobjects

I have a csv file wich contains three columns: ID, latitude and longitude. These latitudes and longitudes are taken from a projection in OSGB36.

How can I possibly convert these latitudes and longitudes in this OSGB36 projection to latitudes and longitudes in WG84?

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/projections_and_transformations/transformations_in_fme.htm

Comment: Copy/Paste your lat/lngs into http://ww2.scenic-tours.co.uk/serve.php?t=WoNlbJvoVlhuJL5405objaa8jVO8atNuwZV

Comment: @Mapperz that tool doesn't take OSGB36 lat/lon values

Comment: That's right, Mapperz doesn't seem to have the option to convert form lat/lon in OSGB36 into lat/lon in WG84 but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using FME, and want to get a new CSV file as output, then generate a workspace from CSV format to CSV format. Use the AttributeReprojector transformer to reproject the x/y attributes.

Comment: Hi Mark, the problem I have is that the parameters for the AttributeReprojector are X and Y attributes, whereas the initial source file has latitude and longitude (measured in degrees) so that they are not equivalent to X and Y.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Just pick longitude for X and latitude for Y. If the degrees are DMS (rather than decimal degrees) then you can convert them first with the DecimalDegreesCalculator transformer

Comment: Mark,
Thanks for your reply. It seemed to work using the AttributeReprojecter. The X parameter has to linked to my Longitudes and the Y to the Latitudes. In addition, intead of using the OSGB36 and WGS84 projections as such, it's better to use their SRIDs (EPSG:4277 & EPSG:4326).